# "No document to update" after trying to update document in Firebase Database in Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to update documents relative to the current user through a button after they edit some textFields.

Here is the code of the button:

```
    @IBAction func bottoneModifica(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let nuovoNome = textFieldNome.text
    print(nuovoNome!)
    db.collection("utenti").document(userID).updateData([
        "name": nuovoNome!
    ]) { errore in
        if let errore = errore {
            print("Error updating document: \(errore)")
        } else {
            print("Document successfully updated")
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the structure of my DB:
[image]

Yes, I do get the correct UID from the userID document, so I'm actually getting to the current user.

I get this error when I click on the button:

> 2021-11-18 17:43:02.928783+0100 My Personal Budget[43805:1072014] 8.9.0 - [Firebase/Firestore][I-FST000001] WriteStream (7fd85db599b8) Stream error: 'Not found: No document to update: projects/my-personal-budget-82e61/databases/(default)/documents/utenti/PwPTjBiPFPYYd7VlFHyE900sYs12'
>
> Error updating document: Error Domain=FIRFirestoreErrorDomain Code=5
> "No document to update:
> projects/my-personal-budget-82e61/databases/(default)/documents/utenti/PwPTjBiPFPYYd7VlFHyE900sYs12"
> UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=No document to update:
> projects/my-personal-budget-82e61/databases/(default)/documents/utenti

/PwPTjBiPFPYYd7VlFHyE900sYs12}

This is the actual UID of the current user:

> PwPTjBiPFPYYd7VlFHyE900sYs12

As you can see i'm in the correct place in the DB.

This is the textField were I get the input.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3gKl.png)

Comment: Your collection is called `utenti`, but your code calls it `users`. You'll want to change one or the other, so that they. match.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Looks as the best answer, could you please post it as Answer for Community's benefit?

Comment: @NestorDanielOrtegaPerez An answer that is unlikely to help anyone but OP, so I voted to close the question as a typo. Additional votes to that effect appreciated. 

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen the typo was actually corrected and it wasn't the problem with the code...

Comment: This was definitely an error in your code, and it still is present in the code in the question. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

In your new error it mentions a user `PwPTjBiPFPYYd7VlFHyE900sYs12`, which is not showing in the database screenshot you shared, so that document indeed also seems to not exist.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I corrected the typo also on the question. Also, the UID I wanted to show is exactly that one, as you can see in the user data it's there.

Comment: There's another typo in the question `"name": nuovoNome!` and the Firestore image shows the field name being `nome`. Lastly, if you're storing users by their uid `.document(userID)` the uid field showing in the document in question does not match that. They should be the same if that's the intention. Which means if you're attempting to update document with uid `PwPTjBiPFPYYd7VlFHyE900sYs12`, that doesn't exist in the shown structure. Lastly, don't include links in the question; links tend to break over time and future readers will have no idea what that's a link to.